# Split string at first occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling splitting the following string into two pieces. Mainly because the one of the possible delimiters is a space character, which can appear in the second capture group.

https://regex101.com/r/dS0bD8/1

How can I split these strings at either `\s`, `\skeyword\s`, or `\skey\s`?

```
'[] []' // => ['[]', '[]']
'[] keyword []' // => ['[]', '[]']
'[] key []' // => ['[]', '[]']

'[] ["can contain spaces"]'  // => ['[]', '["can contain spaces"]']
'[] keyword ["can contain spaces"]' // => ['[]', '["can contain spaces"]']
'[] key ["can contain spaces"]' // => ['[]', '["can contain spaces"]']

'{} {}' // => ['{}', '{}']
'{} keyword {}' // => ['{}', '{}']
'{} key {}' // => ['{}', '{}']

'{} {"can":"contain spaces"}' // => ['{}', '{"can":"contain spaces"}']
'{} keyword {"can":"contain spaces"}' // => ['{}', '{"can":"contain spaces"}']
'{} key {"can":"contain spaces"}' // => ['{}', '{"can":"contain spaces"}']

'string string' // => ["string", "string"]
'string keyword string' // => ["string", "string"]
'string key string' // => ["string", "string"]
```

Comment: You want to use a single regex to match all the previous cases ?

Comment: What about taking a step back and removing all instances of `keyword` and `key` then using Regex?

Comment: What's wrong with the regex you have? Note that this tool is using a test STRING singular, and is therefore assuming that everything in the input is one long string, when you are intending for them to be multiple individual strings.

Comment: @Hamms the regex I have splits every space character :/

Comment: @SumnerEvans I'm curious how you can have or options and only match the first instance. It's apart of the question.

Comment: don't use the global option with it

Comment: @ThomasReggi from where you want to split `["can contain spaces"]'`

Comment: @ThomasReggi, thanks for clarifying. None of the examples had more than one group after `keyword` or `key`.

Comment: @Redu the first space character in the string.

Comment: @Hammsr removing global does not work https://jsbin.com/fudeneleqe/edit?js,console

Comment: @ThomasReggi you can use ``(\S+?) `` and then append an optional non capturing group to match for *keyword* and *key*

Comment: @ThomasReggi I would point to this as one of the "model" questions on Stack Overflow. You had done your part. You gave all the supporting details, gave a way for us to try it out ourselves. Great question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(\skeyword\s|\skey\s|\s(?=.*[\[{]|[^\]}]+$))
```

Will work for all the cases you gave.
[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dS0bD8/3).

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you James! Unfortunately the `string string` case needs to include alpha-numeric and symbols not just word characters. How can I add this in? :) `(\skeyword\s|\skey\s|\s(?=.*[\[{]|[a-z0-9-]+$))`?

Comment: @JamesBuck hey, just found this fails `{} {"can": []}` you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @JamesBuck is there any way to only capture the first space? It's an odd bug.

Comment: @ThomasReggi you could try a negative lookahead instead to verify the space is not inside a `{}` or `[]` block - `(\skeyword\s|\skey\s|\s(?![^[]+]$|[^{]+}$))`. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS0bD8/4). I don't know a way to check it's the first space without using a lookbehind or `\K` reset (both of which the JavaScript regex engine doesn't support).

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `"keyword"` and `"key"` with empty string `""`, then split `\s+`

```
str.replace(/keyword|key/g, "").split(/\s+/)
```

Comment: @ThomasReggi You could alternatively replace `keyword|key` with comma character `,` then call `.split(/,/)`